# Moving a Specific Point in the Recordset in Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a function written in Access VBA. The purpose of this function is to perform simple linear interpolation. It interpolates a "ZeroRate" value for a specified date, using the ZeroRates for the closest "MaturityDates" dates drawn from an inputted recordset. The function is as follows:

```
  Function CurveInterpolateRecordset(rsCurve As Recordset, InterpDate As 
    Date) as Double


    Dim Q As Long

    Dim x1 As Date, x2 As Date, y1 As Double, y2 As Double, x As Date

    CurveInterpolateRecordset = Rnd()

    If rsCurve.RecordCount <> 0 Then

        Q = 1

        rsCurve.MoveFirst

        x1 = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate"))

        y1 = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate"))

        If InterpDate = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate")) Then CurveInterpolateRecordset = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate")): Exit Function


        rsCurve.MoveNext

        Do While (CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate")) <= InterpDate)
            If rsCurve.EOF Then CurveInterpolateRecordset = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate")): Exit Function

            If InterpDate = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate")) Then CurveInterpolateRecordset = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate")): Exit Function

            If InterpDate > CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate")) Then

            x1 = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate"))
            y1 = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate"))

            End If

            rsCurve.MoveNext
            If rsCurve.EOF Then CurveInterpolateRecordset = y1: Exit Function

        Loop

            x2 = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate"))
            y2 = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate"))

            CurveInterpolateRecordset = y1 + (y2 - y1) * CDate((InterpDate - x1) / (x2 - x1))
    End If



End Function
```

Right now, the function begins at the beginning of the recordset defined by rsCurve.MoveFirst and moves through the recordset from there until the end of the recordset rsCurve.EOF. It interpolates over these values. However, I do not want it to always begin at the beginning of the recordset.

Instead, I want it to begin at a specific point in the recordset. I have a column of dates in the recordset called "MarkAsOfDate". Instead of interpolating over the entire recordset, I want it to only interpolate where MarkAsofDate equals some user-inputted value. So for 7/31/2015, I want it to interpolate using the values from rows where the MarkAsofDate column is equal to 7/31/2015. How can I change the rsCurve.MoveFirst to accomplish this? I tried using Do While commands but without success.

Comment: You could try the recordset.seek method.  This requires an index.  See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff836416.aspx.  Alternatively, you could use Do While as you mentioned....Do While rsCurve!MarkAsOfDate <> desiredValue rsCurve.MoveNext Loop then add another loop...Do While rsCurve!MarkAsOfDate = desiredValue....do stuff rsCurve.MoveNext Loop

Comment: why not run the query filtered with the user-input date criteria?

Comment: ^^ This. Open `rsCurve` with only the data you want, by using a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Set rsCurve = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate >= #" & txtUserInputDate.Value & "# ORDER BY MyDate ASC")
```

You will have to change obvious info such as table name, textbox name and field names, but that's the general idea.